# Database design for authorized user to create account

Tags: php, mysql

I'm planning to build a little Social Networking style project for my school,and I'm having a little trouble creating my database design. for ex: Visitors can create an account if they are registered in our school. They need to give their Student Numbers and their First name,Last Name,Middle Name and Course etc.

The application should generate a unique verification code. The code will be sent in the Student's e-mail address. When the Student is ready to activate their account, they should enter their Student Number and the verification code generated by the application, if the verification code and the Student number matched in our database, they will automatically directed to a page where they can input their User Name and Password.

**Verification Table**

```
ID,StudentNumber,Code,FirstName,LastName,MiddleName,Gender,Course.
```

**User Table**

```
ID,StudentNumber,UserName,Password,E-mail.
```

**Users Profile Table**

```
ID,StudentNumber,Code,FirstName,LastName,MiddleName,Gender,Course.
```

Any suggestions in my design above?

Answer (score 0):

## Verification table is obsolote

When a User registers. He is entered into the verification table. If the then clicks the email, you have this massive code that copies fields from verification to user + profile.

Adding a field to the profile, means you will have to do the same to Verification.

Simply add a field 'verified' in the user table. and then change your queries:

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE verified = true;
```

Or you could opt for a status field. Users could for instance be verified, but blocked because of trolling.

## Studentnumber is the primary key

Then, Why is there en ID column? The studentnumber is unique... Simply use that as primary key and get rid of that ID floating around

## Columnnames

don't use - or capitals in your column names. Just don't.

## DB design

At this moment, there is a User has a Profile and Profile has a Course.

so if a user enrolls into 2 courses, he will have 2 profiles? Good luck keeping those profiles in sync.

## Code is not profile

I think with the column code you mean the verification code? If so, call it verification_code

And why is it part of profile? It should be part of the user.

Atheistbless!

Answer (score 0):

Why use so many tables? Just one User table is enough.

User

> ID, StudentNumber, UserName, Password, E-mail, FirstName, LastName, MiddleName, Gender, Course, VerificationCode, IsVerified

This way you can hold all the information you need.
Then when you need verification, just query the username and verification code then compare it to the one user provided. The column `IsVerified` should be int(1), you can set the default to 0. And if the user success in the verification, you change it to 1.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry! why you need three tables for just storing user detail and the verification code,use single table for both of them.

You just need to use only the verification table designed by you that is right.